# How to get UL and LI value dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a simple ul and li tags which contains state and capitals, here I need to get all the data from json dynamically and to append into main div of class "details",Here I just hardcoded but actually it should come from json given below in the same way.Here is the code below

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
<ul>
<li>state</li>
<li>
<ul>state1</ul>
<ul>state2</ul>
</li>
<li>capital</li>
<li>
<ul>capital1</ul>
<ul>capital2</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "sample.json",
     success: function(result)
     {
     console.log(result);

     }
     });

    });
```

### json

```
{
    "state": [{
            "name": "state1"
        },
        {
            "name": "state2"
        }
    ],
    "capital": [{
            "name": "capital1"
        },
        {
            "name": "capital2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word of warning: your proposed markup isn't [valid](https://validator.w3.org/) (`Error: Text not allowed in element ul in this context.`). Even so, it sounds like it's the appropriate output for this task.

I'll assume your Ajax request is working and returns a valid JSON structure as the `result` variable.

Having handled set up, here's the code to generate your structure:

```js
const result = {
  "state": [
    {"name": "state1"},
    {"name": "state2"}
  ],
  "capital": [
    {"name": "capital1"},
    {"name": "capital2"}
  ]
};

const root = document.createElement("ul");
document.querySelector(".details").appendChild(root);

for (const key in result) {
  const title = document.createElement("li");
  title.innerText = key;
  root.appendChild(title);

  const list = document.createElement("li");
  root.appendChild(list);
  
  for (const o of result[key]) {
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.innerText = o.name;
    list.appendChild(ul);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="details"></div>
```

Comment: Hi ggorlen,thanks for your answer,but here I can't change ul li structure since I am using it for accordion. and those values inside the ul li should be rendered completely through json value of my  json file given above  with ajax call,To show I have just hardcoded it.

Comment: I can't replicate your Ajax call, so you'll need to post an absolute path to `sample.json` so I can produce a full, runnable example. But since that doesn't seem to be the problem (you are getting a response JSON, correct?), I recommend eliminating that component from your question to produce a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for the structure, also post the complete, minimal code to show what you're trying to do, i.e. with accordion and rationale. The markup looks like a mistake to me, but it's just a matter of shifting around a few element tags in the answer.

Comment: Here I am trying to fetch from json and I am trying to create  <ul><li></li></ul> through script and data from json and append inside <li> of class state1,but its not working.This is my plunker link   http://plnkr.co/edit/CpLAZZwtmJG9KnOPfISX?p=preview

Comment: Well, you didn't use my code and your JS script wasn't running. This works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/a5Low4AeI6NSO2ynqMi0.